# I'm getting an error when I try to access `EnginePower` from Unity StandardAssets script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Im trying to access the variable "EnginePower" from the script `AeroplaneController` see code below

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Speed : MonoBehaviour
{
public GameObject Aircraft;
public Text SpeedText;
public float FSpeed;

// Update is called once per frame
 void Update()
 {
    FSpeed = Aircraft.GetComponent<AeroplaneController>().EnginePower * 5.714285714285714;  
 }
}
```

As you can see, Im setting `FSpeed` to be equal to `EnginePower` multiplied by `5.714285714285714`
But im getting the error `The type or namespace name 'AeroplaneController' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

`EnginePower` IS public, AeroplaneController is a `Unity StandardAssets` script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding to what @LafiteCandy said:

Change `Aircraft.GetComponent<AeroplaneController>()` to `Aircraft.GetComponent<UnityStandardAssets.Vehicles.Aeroplane.AeroplaneController>()`

Comment: That seemed to have worked! Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

`AeroplaneController` might be in another namespace

Try using `XXXnamespace.AeroplaneController`, or just add a using at the beginning of the code

Comment: How do I add it to the using at the beginning? `using Aircraft.GeroplanController;` ?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).